# Google map api v3: Set cursor with custom message

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me figure out how to set the cursor with some custom message just like below website

http://www.rightmove.co.uk/draw-a-search.html

They are showing custom message as 'Click and release to place your first point' which later changes to 'Click on map to draw an edge'.

Comment: Copy their JS from http://www.rightmove.co.uk/ps/js24250/concat/js_main_v1/drawASearch.js - it's been minified, so run it through something like http://jsbeautifier.org/ - it's about 1700 lines long. I think you need to give more details to your question about exactly what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That effects is done with both CSS and Javascript, nothing to do with Google Maps. With CSS you will change the cursor and with Javascript you can show, hide and move the message. For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="cursor-div">
</div>

<div id="cursor-message">
    <p>Message cursor</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cursor-div{
    cursor: crosshair;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

#cursor-message{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$("#cursor-div").mousemove(function(event){
   $("#cursor-message").css("top",event.pageY-20);
   $("#cursor-message").css("left",event.pageX+20);
});

$("#cursor-div").mouseenter(function(event){
    $("#cursor-message").show();
});

$("#cursor-div").mouseleave(function(event){
    $("#cursor-message").hide();
});
```

And here you can see it working: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t394etaa/)**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Google Maps.  It's their own custom JS.  Check this fiddle for an example of how to do get started with it, using jQuery for speed.

http://jsfiddle.net/g1t50jrg/1/

```
$('.container').on( 'mousemove', function(event){

    $('.hint').css({
        top: event.pageY - 15,
        left: event.pageX + 20
    });

});
```